# Не приходит подтверждение оплаты IPN в sandbox от paypal

Tags: paypal

Здравствуйте! Не приходит подтверждение оплаты IPN в sandbox от paypal?
Сайт указан правильно куда отправлять подтверждение.

В файле который принимает запросы сделал проверку содержимого:

file_put_contents('./debug.txt', serialize($_POST) );

Ничего не приходит. На домене не используется https. Обязательно ли должен быть https? Если да то будет ли работать с самозаверенным сертификатом?

Answer (score 0):

Запросы начали приходить просто не сразу оказывается. Нашел ошибку у себя в коде обработчика  было подключение $curl к paypal, а не к sandbox.